# No module named 'pwd' while use 'from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader'

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

When I start to use webloader with 'from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader'
then got error of missing 'pwd' module
[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxgaj.png)

Answer (score 3):

This bug has already been fixed on [GitHub langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/commit/7ae3ce60d2f572e4781c9eb87033eb2c5950b628).
We have to wait for the next version of `langchain-community`.
Now you can install the previous `pip install langchain-community==0.0.19`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in my RAG model in `python 3.11.4`

```py
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
```